# Mobile App With Web Admin Panel

Tags: ios, swift, rest, parse-platform, backend

I have to build an iOS mobile app which has a web based admin panel.

Can you give me some tips on where to start?

I know OOP programming and the fundamentals of Swift (I have to use this language.)

The app I would like to build is kind of a reporting app. Users can log in to their dashboards and can send reports to the "office" which means they fill out a specific form. In the office managers can check the reports in a custom made web based admin panel (such as www.domain.com/reports-admin) where they can log in and view,filter,delete,save these reports.

Can I do something like this with Parse.com or I have to build my own backend from scratch?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the backend, it doesn't matter if you are delivering the content to an iOS app or a Web interface.  So yes your users can access it from the web or their iOS device.  Parse.com can be easily used for the backend as they support many languages.  The [parse.com](https://parse.com/docs/api_libraries) documentation is a good place to start.

Comment: Thank your for the reply, it was really helpful. I'll try to do this with Swift 2, PHP, JAVASCRIPT, HTML and CSS.

Let me ask another question (I'm an IT student not a professional...). In this solution I have to create 2 databases one for the users and one for the reports. And in the report database I have to store the user id who made it. Is it correct?

And I can communicate between the ios app and parse.com with JSON.

Thank you...

Comment: Do you mean databases or tables?  I suggest you learn about database design before you use a database or parse.com and then have someone review your design.

Comment: 2 tables, sorry... English is not my native language sometimes I mix up these things.

Comment: You can have two tables (or parse objects) and have one reference the other, you can also have 3 tables: reports, users, and a mapping table to map users to reports.